# Top Down Web Service on Google App Engine in Java

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine, cxf

Has anyone managed to develop a top down web service (WSDL first) and deployed to Google App Engine. The example given at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/soap is a bottom up approach.

I've used Apache CXF to generate Java web service stubs from a WSDL, bundled in the app engine libraries and xml config files, but no joy. I see an `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/JMException` in the App Engine logs when initialising the `CXFServlet`, which is pretty nasty. `ClassNotFoundException` I could maybe do something about, but `NoClassDefFoundError` is indicative of a class that was available at compile time that is not available at runtime. `JMException` is a JDK class, so I would expect it to be available.

I'm not so bothered in fixing the `Exception`, I'm more interested in whether anyone has a proof of concept for a top down web service in Java on GAE

Comment: Hmm. I ended up doing a workaround. I used Red Hat's OpenShift instead, with a 'diy' install of Tomcat. I'm still interested if anyone has managed to develop a wsdl driven java web service on GAE

Answer (score 0):

I also read the article you mentioned, as well as this exercise: [Code Lab Exercise 5: SOAP Web Services](http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise5.html)

What I understood from those two sources (and some others) is, that the top down / contract first approach is currently **not supported** by GAE for building WS-*servers* (while building WS-*clients* using jax-ws is supported).

At least thats how I understand those statements:

> Starting in release 1.4.2 of Google App Engine, it is possible to use java.xml.soap and JAX-B to build a SOAP server, and to use JAX-WS to build a SOAP client on App Engine.
>   [...]
>
> As of version 1.4.2 Google App Engine does not support the use of JAX-WS in a SOAP server. (It is supported in a SOAP client.) As we'll see below, in order to complete the SOAP server we will have to directly use javax.xml.soap and JAX-B. [2](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/soap?hl=de)

Bluddy